# Wordpress dashboard RSS feed for theme messages

Tags: wordpress, rss, wordpress-theming

I have created a wordpress theme and need to put an RSS feed on the dashboard whereby I can add messages to the feed at my end and it will appear on every install of the theme globally. I am guessing I just need to create an rss feed dashboard widget that subscribes to an rss feed of my choice. Is there anything out there that does this already? I can't seem to find anything and seems like it should be a pretty standard feature.